# How to deal with overwhelming Jenkins updates to core and plugins?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I love Jenkins and appreciate that it is an active project. Still, I don't know what would be the correct approach for maintaining a Jenkins installation because I do see Jenkins+plugins updates daily and this takes too much time to update them.

Is there a way to automate this or a LTS version that I can use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jenkins team do have a concept of LTS releases, so take a look at this Wiki: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LTS+Release+Line

As for automating updates, you can do it if you've installed Jenkins using a package manager at the OS level. For instance, on ubuntu you could have a cron that calls `apt-get update` and `apt-get install jenkins` at midnight. I'm not sure about automating if you've installed it manually.

However, automatic updates have a bad side, as essential plugins could potentially stop working with new updates, or bugs that have slipped through the net could cause problems.

Having said that, the quality of Jenkins seems consistently good, so it might be worth the risk for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to automate the update.

However, given the fact that an update could (in theory, Jenkins has been completely stable in my experience) break something in your build process, I don't think automating would be an appropriate solution.

What seems to work well for me is to periodically do the updates manually and then re-run all of the build jobs to verify that nothing has broken. I do this as part of our regular maintenance when we do VM backups and operating system updates on our CI environment. (The updates are done after the backups so that if something does go wrong, we have an up-to-date fall back point..)